# How to Query by a posts custom metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

So I am trying to filter my post list by 'seen' So far I have a function that is saving the any users who have seen any given post to a meta field called 'logged_viewers' and I have verified that it is working since I can print out its contents in a `<ul>` in the posts content

I am using an elementor loop grid with a custom query ID.

The following code that is supposed to show only the posts the current user has NOT seen but it is not working and i cant seem to figure out why

```
function query_by_seen( $query ) {

    // Get current meta Query
    $meta_query = $query->get( 'meta_query' );
    // Get meta data
    $userID = get_current_user_id();
    $viewers_list = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'logged_viewers', true );

    // If there is no meta query when this filter runs, it should be initialized as an empty array.
    if ( ! $meta_query ) {
        $meta_query = [];
    }

    // Append our meta query
    $meta_query[] = [
        'key' => $viewers_list,
        'value' => $userID,
        'compare' => 'NOT IN',
    ];

    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}
add_action( 'elementor/query/query_by_seen', 'query_by_seen' );
```

The following code populates the `logged_viewers` field:

```
function log_viewers() {
        global $post;
    
        $viewers_nonce  = wp_create_nonce( 'viewers_nonce_' . $post->ID );
        $userID         = get_current_user_id();
        $viewers        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'logged_viewers', true );  
        
        if( empty( $viewers ) ) {
            $viewers = array();
        }
    
        $viewers[]      = $userID;
        $viewers_list   = array_unique( $viewers );
    
        if( !wp_verify_nonce( $viewers_nonce, 'viewers_nonce_' . $post->ID ) ) {
            die();
        }
        else {
            update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'logged_viewers', $viewers_list );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'log_viewers' );
```

I am newer to PHP so I might just be missing something but any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters), when using `NOT IN`, `value` is expected to be an array. That means the comparison takes the value from the meta data, and compares it against the values in the array that's provided:

> value (string|array) – Custom field value. It can be an array only when compare is 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', or 'NOT BETWEEN'.

This means that passing an integer to `value` and the meta data being an array will not work. I tested a few approaches with this scheme, and couldn't get any to work correctly.

The approach that will work, is to store the IDs of the posts that the user has seen in user's meta data, and then compare against that.

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', static function () {
    if ( ! is_single() ) {
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $viewed  = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'viewed_ids' );

    if ( in_array( $post_id, $viewed ) ) {
        return;
    }

    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'viewed_ids', $post_id );
} );

function query_by_seen( $query ) {
    $user_id      = get_current_user_id();
    $viewed       = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'viewed_ids' );
    $post__not_in = $query->get( 'post__not_in', array() );

    $post__not_in = array_merge( $post__not_in, $viewed );
    $post__not_in = array_unique( $post__not_in );

    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $post__not_in );
} );
```

If you need to know on the post which users have viewed, then add that to the `wp_head` callback after `add_user_meta()`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_head', static function () {
    ...

    add_user_meta( ... );

    $viewed = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'logged_viewers' );

    if ( in_array( $user_id, $viewed ) ) {
        return;
    }

    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'logged_viewers', $user_id );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, the snippet is working now but not as expected.
For some reason it only returns the posts i have viewed when `compare` is set to **NOT IN** or **LIKE**. When set to **IN** or **NOT LIKE** it returns nothing
Do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Your comment seems contradictory: will you please review and edit or post a new comment clarifying?

Comment: So, using the code you provided above,, the query is now returning all the posts the user has viewed when `compare` is set to **NOT IN** which is the opposite of what i would expect **NOT IN** to return. After seeing this I tried using **IN** instead of **NOT IN** in an attempt to invert it and get all the posts the user has not seen but after making that change it didn't return anything at all.

Comment: Hmm, can you edit your question to include the code that populates `logged_viewers` meta?

Comment: yes, i went ahead and updated that so you can see 

Comment: Cool. I'll implement in a test environment tomorrow and attempt to replicate your issue.

Comment: Thanks! Also: after some further testing, it seems as tho the query is only returning posts where `logged_viewers` is not empty.

Hopefully that is helpful information.

Comment: Updated my answer: previously discussed approach will not work.